# Error when in conditional statments are 2 "or"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Ansible Version: 2.9

Main goal: Run task on every OS except: RedHat/AlmaLinux/CentOS/CloudLinux in and above 8 version.

I run this role on AlmaLinux 8.6

In some task, I have the following conditions:

```yaml
  when: 
    - (ansible_facts['os_family'] != "RedHat" and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] >= "8") or
      (ansible_facts['distribution'] != "AlmaLinux" and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] >= "8")
```

And when this role is running on AlmaLinux 8, it is skipped – properly.

```yaml
  when: 
    - (ansible_facts['os_family'] != "RedHat" and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] >= "8") or
      (ansible_facts['distribution'] != "AlmaLinux" and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] >= "8") or
      (ansible_facts['distribution'] != "CloudLinux" and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] >= "8")
```

After I add next condition, task every time failed. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the conditions.

```yaml
when: 
  - ansible_facts['os_family'] != "RedHat"
  - ansible_facts['distribution'] not in ["AlmaLinux", "CloudLinux"]
  - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] | int >= 8
```

Comment: 1. It would not work, becouse of :" int >= 8", as I said "Ansible Version: 2.9",

2.  " - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] | int >= 8 " This conditional will affect on OS-es f.e Debian 8+ etc.,

Certain task should run everywhere, except RedHat/AlmaLinux/CloudLinux/CentOS in >= 8 version